# FilterSearch doesn't work propely

Tags: magento2

I have a question about filterSearch. While I type '27000000002'. It doesn't work properly. (See below picture)
  [image: o]

This is my setting on the .xml file.

```
  <dataSource name="acer_pushorderstatus_grid_data_source" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider">
    <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
        <!--class is for php-->
        <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider</argument>
        <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">acer_pushorderstatus_grid_data_source</argument>
        <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
        <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
            </item>
            <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">order_number</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </argument>
</dataSource>
```

And filterSearch code is below

```
<listingToolbar name="listing_top">
    <bookmark name="bookmarks"/>
    <columnsControls name="columns_controls"/>
    <exportButton name="export_button"/>
    **<filterSearch name="fulltext"/>**
    <filters name="listing_filters"/>
    <paging name="listing_paging"/>
</listingToolbar>
```

Is anyone knows how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After checking my databases, I realize I have to add  "INDEX_TYPE_FULLTEXT" to UpgradeSchema.php (See below picture)

[image]

Then search bar works.

Happy coding.